# Disable visual editor on one specific page

Tags: functions, pages, visual-editor

I would like to remove the visual editor from one specific page because if I edit this one page in Visual mode, it breaks the code. I want to make sure the client doesn't have this option on the particular page. However, I don't want to remove the html editor.

This line of code removes the visual editor and the html editor:           remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');

a closer look at remove_post_type_support:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_post_type_support

But I want to only disable the visual editor.

Initial testing, in functions.php for this theme, I have:

```
function remove_editor_init() {

 if ( is_admin() ) {
    if (is_page(2548)) { 


    remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
    }
 }
}
add_action('init', 'remove_editor_init');
```

However, the conditional statements is_admin() and is_page() don't seem to working together.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code, calling the action `admin_init` makes `is_admin()` unnecessary. And, if not mistaken, [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) is meant to be used in the front-end...

But the solution is the following (based on [this Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18149/12615)):

```
add_filter( 'user_can_richedit', 'wpse_58501_page_can_richedit' );

function wpse_58501_page_can_richedit( $can ) 
{
    global $post;

    if ( 28 == $post->ID )
        return false;

    return $can;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've resolved this:

```
add_filter( 'admin_footer', 'removes_editor_visual_tab', 99 );

function removes_editor_visual_tab()
{
    $post_id = $_GET['post'];
    if($post_id == 1434){
    ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        a#content-tmce, a#content-tmce:hover {
            display:none;
        }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            document.getElementById("content-tmce").onclick = 'none';
        });
        </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

You can select the page ID(s) that you'd like this to reflect on